# is it possible to extract compilation statistics from vs 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, statistics, solid-state-drive

For instance, I want to find out how many times I built the solution in a day and how long the process took in total (per day).

I want to buy an ssd and I am not convinced it would save me a lot of time based on my current pattern of computer usage, so I want to go more scientifically about it. I spend most of my time typing, thinking as well, and compiling a C# solution with a few projects (on my current hdd it takes about 5-15s to compile the solution) and possibly in the future Java code. Everybody says they are very fast but the price holds me back.

Thanks

Comment: Possibly a cheaper alternative: get more RAM if you can. Compilation is a lot slower when the HDD is being thrashed due to not enough memory.